# How to configure Voce with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, voice-recognition

I'm planning on making a voice recognition program and found Voce to be the way to do it in C++ (the only language I know how to program in). Unfortunately I don't know how to set it up to start using it. Can someone help me get it to work in Visual Studio?

Voce: http://voce.sourceforge.net/

Information:
Windows 8.1 64-bit
Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Voce is not something you would like to use. On Windows you can use microsoft SAPI, it is in C++: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125077(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial or documentation on how to configure it to work with Visual Studio (2013)?

Comment: I provided you the link on the documentation above, you just need to click on it and read it carefully